# Pattern matching condition ensures neither property is null, but compiler issues a possible null reference warning. Why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, language-lawyer, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I have reproduced a very small code example below. In my code I am explicitly checking that `AboveValue` and `BelowValue` are both not null, and this works for `BelowValue` (no warning) but not for `AboveValue` (warning of possible null reference). Given my conditions, I don't see how the compiler imagines `AboveValue` can be null at this point in the code.

Note that the face `AboveValue` is part of base interface is critical to reproduce the issue - code does not show any warnings if both properties are in the IBelow interface, shows warnings for both if both are in `IAbove` interface.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Code needed to build the project");


public interface IAbove
{
    string? AboveValue { get; }
}

public interface IBelow : IAbove
{
    string? BelowValue { get; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Execute(IAbove above)
    {
        if (above is IBelow { AboveValue: not null, BelowValue: not null } belowTest1)
        {
            // warning CS8602: Dereferencing of a possible null reference
            Console.WriteLine(belowTest1.AboveValue.Length);
            // ok
            Console.WriteLine(belowTest1.BelowValue.Length);
        }
        if (above is not IBelow { AboveValue: not null, BelowValue: not null } belowTest2)
        {
            return;
        }
        // warning CS8602: Dereferencing of a possible null reference
        Console.WriteLine(belowTest2.AboveValue.Length);
        // ok
        Console.WriteLine(belowTest2.BelowValue.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but look at my pattern matching. Why there is no warning on BelowValue so?

Comment: OK, I see what you're getting at now. It seems like it might be a bug. I sense it's checking `AboveValue` in the context of `IAbove`, but then in the code inside the if statement, it's checking it in the context of `IBelow`, which it feels like it hasn't checked already. That's my gut feeling anyway, since nothing else makes sense. It's probably best to report it as a bug.

Comment: Yes exactly I get 3 thumbs down without any explanation in 2 minutes and I think that the people who put them have hardly looked at my example... Thank you for taking the time to look at

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question a little in the hopes that it is clearer to other people reading it. I certainly misread it initially.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to re-look at your question instead of calling everyone #$%#$. So far it reads as "C# compiler is POS and I'm f**ing awesome." It would be significantly better to replace title with some meaningful text explaining what you trying to do and replace body with your reasoning why code should not show the warning. (like @ProgrammingLlama did...)

Comment: Whoever is interested to answer I've added interesting note to the question about where property had to be located to show warning. There is something with inherited properties that triggers warning or more likely prevents analysis.(I've also added "language-lawyer" as tag as this is likely require some deep understanding of the spec even if the answer is "we just give up")

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I thought my question was clear enough with a very simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) explains the problem, the pattern is translated to the following code.

```
IBelow below = above as IBelow;
if (below != null && above.AboveValue != null && below.BelowValue != null)
```

The compiler (not intelligent enough?) thinks `AboveValue` belongs to `above` so it only determines `above.AboveValue` is not null. If the type of `above` is not `IAbove`, e.g. `object above`, then it checks `belowTest1.AboveValue != null`

Comment: I reported the issue. Thank you

Comment: Link to the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/65306